# Close only a specific tab with firefox extension

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

i'm developing a firefox extension and i want to be able to close a specific tab. For example if there are many open tabs in the browser o want to close only the tab with a specific url.

I know that i can use gBrowser.removeTab(tab) but i don't know how to get tab object. 
On the other hand i can get the browser that corresponds to the url but the param of the removeTab() function must be a "tab object". How cat i get the tab object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

[`tabbrowser.getBrowserForTab()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserForTab) is actually the easiest way of associating browsers with tabs. So you would do something like this:

```js
var tabs = gBrowser.tabs;
for (var i = tabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var tab = tabs[i];
  var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
  if (browser.currentURI && browser.currentURI.spec == "...")
    gBrowser.removeTab(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this method: `gBrowser.removeCurrentTab();` this example closes the currently selected tab.

For more code, please refers this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser